# Set different appSettings key in production server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web.config-transform

How can I set a different value when I publish my MVC5 do production server?

Example:

In dev I have

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="XLSFile" value="C:\\temp\\file.xls" />
</appSettings>
```

And when I publish the project I want to set a different path:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="XLSFile" value="C:\\projectname\\file.xls" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: You're going to want to use an XmlUpdate task in MSBuild.  What method are you using for deployment?

Comment: Hi, I use Visual Studio Publish tool.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use a [config file transformation](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations). Essentially you will override the config file for your release build.

For example:

```
<add key="XLSFile" value="C:\\projectname\\file.xls" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
```

Comment: Hi, in your link they use xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" and you are using Replace, why?

Comment: Force of habit. In this case either should work. Replace will replace the whole key and its children. SetAttribute will set the attribute and may be the better option in this case

Answer (score 1):

You can use two config files one with name **web.Debug.config** and second **web.Release.config**. First one for development and second for production server when published and now specify different value of key in both files as required